# test for clicking on a rect in Python

Tags: python, click, pygame

I can't figure out a way to detect whether the player has clicked within a rect in Pygame. I tried

```
    self.mouserect=(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), 8,8)
```

and then later

```
    if self.click: #(this is true if mouse button is down)
        if self.mouserect.colliderect(self.a_thing_to_click_on.rect):
            do_stuff
```

but that gives me an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [`rect.collidepoint()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidepoint) ?

```
if self.click: #(this is true if mouse button is down)
   if self.a_thing_to_click_on.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a tuple to `self.mouserect`, not a [Rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). The solution is to wrap a `Rect` around it:

```
self.mouserect=pygame.Rect(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), (8,8))
```